# In a square matrix, where each cell is black or white. Design an algorithm to find the max white sub-square

Tags: c++, c, algorithm, data-structures

In a square matrix, where each cell is black or white. Design an algorithm to find the max white (the whole sub-square is white) sub-square.

a solution with O(n^2):
Scan each column from left to right, for each cell in each column, scan each row to find the max white sub-square.

do you have any better solution ?

thanks

Comment: Sure, thats easy.  Please don't write **give me a solution** type questions.

Comment: thanks. I expected a little more from people in here...

Comment: @user144555 While I certainly do not agree with how the above comments are phrased, you should show what you have attempted to solve the question yourself, and explain why it fails.

Comment: @user144555 Also, while I can read hebrew - use only English here. Explain your situation, and explain you are looking for hints, and not a full solution, in addition to your own solution and why it's not good enough, and you'll get better answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First note that your solution is NOT `O(n^2)`, it is more like `O(n^4)`, because for each cell, you look for the largest matrix that can be of size up to `O(n^2)` itself, so it is totalling to `O(n^4)`.

It can be done however in `O(n^2)`:

First, define 2 auxillary functions (implemented as matrices):

```
whitesLeft(x,y) = number of adjacent white cells on the same row to the left from x,y - exclusive of x,y
whitesUp(x,y) = number of adjacent white cells on the same column up from x,y -  exclusive of x,y
```

Now, define the recursive function:

```
D(0,y) = 0     if (0,y) is black
         1     otherwise
D(x,0) = 0     if (x,0) is black
         1     otherwise
D(x,y) = 0                                                         if  x,y is black
         min{ D(x-1,y-1), whitesLeft(x,y), whitesUp(x,y) } + 1     otherwise
```

The idea is to calculate with `D(x,y)` the biggest square that ends (bottom right) in `(x,y)`. This square is calculated by finding the minimal cells to the left, cells to the up and submatrix that ends at `(x-1,y-1)` that has only white cells.

Note that `D(x,y)` can be calculated efficiently with D[ynamic Programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming) in `O(n^2)`, and the pre-processing to calculate the auxillary functions (matrices) is also `O(n^2)`.

When you are done, post prcess `D` to find the largest value of `D(x,y)` for any `(x,y)` to get the result - this is also `O(n^2)`.